# Arrange text file by new line grouping

Tags: java

I am trying to get the information from this text file:

```
Flinders Street

amy j
leanne j
chris s

1 normal 1 [(o, 21) (o, 17) (t, 3)]
2 underAge 2 [(t, 4) (i, 6)]
3 elderly 3 [(o, 12) (t, 5) (i, 7)] 3
4 normal 4 [(t, 4) (t, 3) (t, 8) (t, 2)]
5 underAge 5 [(o, 20) (i, 12)]
6 underAge 13 [(o, 20) (t, 5) (t, 3)]
7 elderly 25 [(t, 4) (t, 3) (i, 12)] 0
8 normal 27 [(t, 2) (t, 2)]
9 underAge 28 [(i, 2)]
```

And I want to put the staff (amy, leanne and chris) into an arraylist as well as the group below that is a list of customers and values related to them in another arraylist. I have attempted to do just that below:

```
public static void readFile(String file) {
        try {
            //Using the buffered reader to load the file.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input\\" + file));
            int listLocation = 0;
            while (br.ready()) {
                String next = br.readLine().trim();

                if (next.isEmpty()) {
                    listLocation++;
                }
                if (listLocation == 0) {
                    Main.branch = next;
                }else if (listLocation == 1) {
                    Main.staff.add(next);
                }else if (listLocation == 2) {
                    Main.customers.add(next);
                }
                listLocation++;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {  }
    }
```

Here is the current result of running it: [image]

Comment: OK.  What (if anything) goes wrong when you run this?

Comment: Nothing is added to the arraylists, and the size of said arraylists remain 0 http://puu.sh/qlDvF/35155693c4.png

Comment: I think the problem may be that you have `listLocation++` in there twice.  You definitely need it inside that first `if` block, but not at the bottom of the loop.  Maybe remove the second `listLocation++` and try again.

Comment: And if that fails, the best way to find the answer to issues like this is to step through your code with a debugger, and as you go, examine the values of the variables that you expect to change.

Comment: Oh good lord that was so obvious, havnt been coding for a while and that was just silly thanks so much, i shouldnt have needed to ask ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `listLocation++;` after the if-else here:

> ```
> if (next.isEmpty()) {
>     listLocation++;
> }
> if (listLocation == 0) {
>     Main.branch = next;
> }else if (listLocation == 1) {
>     Main.staff.add(next);
> }else if (listLocation == 2) {
>     Main.customers.add(next);
> }
> listLocation++;
> // ^^^ remove this line
> ```

As it is, this is what happens:

- First line of input:

  - Line is not empty
  - `listLocation` is 0, set `Main.branch`
  - Increment `listLocation` to 1
- Second line of input:

  - Line is empty -> increment `listLocation` to 2
  - `listLocation` is 2, add line to `Main.customers` (incorrectly, a bug)
  - Increment `listLocation` to 3
- Remaining lines: `listLocation` gets increment forever, none of the conditions on the value of `listLocation` will match again

Comment: Yeah, and i appredciate the explaination and hopfully it helps someone else but i totally understand what I did wrong and why it was wrong, im just abit out of it atm but thanks so much man!